# Binary combinations of N bits with at most M "1"

Tags: binary, combinations

The total number of binary combinations of N bits is : 2^N.

What is the formula to get the number of possible binary combinations of N bits with the following constraint: we have at most M "1" in each combination (M < N).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total number for binary combination with exactly m "1" is combinatorial `C(n,m)`, so I think the formula is

```
C(n,m) + C(n,m-1) + ... + C(n,1) + 1
```

Comment: I think this is incorrect. For example if N=3 and M=2, we have 3 (and not 2^(3-2)) binary combinations containing 2 "1".

Comment: Sorry for earlier, hasty answer, I've edited it. BTW, if N=3 & M=2, wasn't it 7 combinations (011,101,110,001,010,100,000)? CMIIW

Comment: Yes, but I was talking about your formula 2^(N-M) which you said that it gives the number of combinations if we need exactly M "1" (and not at most M "1")..

Comment: Yeah, you can say I'm kinda drunk before (I'm assuming the "1" is grouped together, which is ridiculous indeed). Anyways, I've tried again and edited the answer.